# Grouping and finding most frequent values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
Protein Peptide
A        AAA
A        AAA
A        ABA
B        AAA
B        ABA
B        ABA
```

But I need to filter my data by finding for each value in column 1 the top occurring value in column 2.

So the output would be like:

```
Protein Peptide
A        AAA
B        ABA
```

In reality I need even top 3 occuring values.
Really don't know how to solve it using python and pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mode isn't a groupby method, though it is a [Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html) (and [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html)) method, so you have to pass it to [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply):

```
In [11]: df.groupby('Protein')['Peptide'].apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
Out[11]:
Protein
A    AAA
B    ABA
Name: Peptide, dtype: object
```

---

To get the top three, you could use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) (in the same way):

```
In [12]: df.groupby('Protein')['Peptide'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()[:3])
Out[12]:
Protein
A        AAA    2
         ABA    1
B        ABA    2
         AAA    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! But my other columns disappeared (mean, sd). How to combine them?

Comment: @MPs sorry missed the question bit, it depends how you want to combine them (I don't think there's no canonical way this would make sense?) Perhaps ask a new question with the input and desired output - I think this question is nice/self contained/googlable atm! :)